# Compare 2 files with multiple columns | shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a 2 files *fil1.txt* and *fil2.txt*

My requirement is to compare **column1** and **column3** of both the files and if it matches then check the **column2** values and if **column2** value is less than equal to column2 value of second file than remove it from the list and print rest entries.

example below-

*fil1.txt* has content

```
abc 25 bcd
xyz 30 efg
pqr 25 qrs
```

*fil2.txt* has content

```
abc 30 bcd
xyz 30 efg
rst 25 uvw
pqs 35 lmn
```

My output should be

```
pqr 25 qrs
```

Below code is working but not sure how I can compare **column2** value.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$3];next} !(($1,$3) in a)' fil1.txt fil2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {a[$1,$3] = $2; next} $2 > a[$1,$3]' file2 file1

pqr 25 qrs
```

Comment: `$2 > a[$1,$3]` is enough to cover the first predicate.